# Coverting json array to js objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json string like this

```
[ { 
"name":"sourabh", 
"userid":"soruabhbajaj", 
"id":"11", 
"has_profile_image":"0" }, 
{
"name":"sourabh", 
"userid":"sourabhbajaj", 
"id":"12", 
"has_profile_image":"0" 
}]
```

Now, I want to convert this json array to the string like this so that I can access any object using its id on the entire page.

```
{ "11": { 
"name":"sourabh", 
"userid":"soruabhbajaj", 
"id":"11", 
"has_profile_image":"0" }, 
"12": {
"name":"sourabh", 
"userid":"sourabhbajaj", 
"id":"12", 
"has_profile_image":"0" 
}}
```

Suggest some code please. Thanx in advance

EDIT:
Will this work:

```
user.(function(){return id;})
```

And then accessing objects like this

```
user.id.name
```

I mean is this a correct way of defining object?

Comment: What stops ***you*** from suggesting some code, and us giving you a pointer in the right direction?

Comment: I tried manipulating the entire string but that didn't seem efficient enough. So I asked for some piece of code which can guide me.

Comment: Do you have access to the code that generates the JSON? That's the easier way to do it, IMO.

Comment: Yeah I have but there are some more limitations so I can't change the format of the JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var data = ... the initial array
var result = {};
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var element = data[i];
    result[element.id] = element;
};
```

Comment: I don't want to take them in arrays. I want to create new objects for every user.

Comment: @Sourabh, you can access each individual user by using `result[123].name`.

Comment: That's a good choice. Thanx. I am editing my question a bit, Check if it works?

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [ 
    {"name":"sourabh", "userid":"soruabhbajaj", "id":"11", "has_profile_image":"0"}, 
    {"name":"sourabh", "userid":"sourabhbajaj", "id":"12", "has_profile_image":"0"}
];

var newData = {};

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var item = data[i];
    newData[item.id] = item;
}
```

Now `newData` is an object where the keys are the ids of the people and the data for each key is the person object itself.  So, you can access an item like this:

```
var id = "11";
var name = newData[id].name;
```